# RTSP over SSL using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp

Is it possible to stream RTSP securely over SSL using ffmpeg? I see that there's no way to pass https for the rtsp_transport option. I've been told it's possible to stream RTSP over HTTPS.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if you use the RTSPS scheme in your URL, it will use TLS as the transport layer protocol. See [rtsp.c](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/a8ce6fb425e07e60eb06d3f44992fdb91f23aafb/libavformat/rtsp.c#L1699)

Answer (score 1):

It works in command line (This is mac one) you can run something like this

ffmpeg -f avfoundation -video_size 640x480 -i "0" -c:v h264 -f rtsp -rtsp_transport tcp rtsps://localhost:8322/mystream

Answer (score -3):

Short answer is No!

ffmpeg does not support rtsp over https . The only option you can pass in to rtsp_transport are udp,tcp,upd_multicast or http .

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#rtsp